# How can I send alert on color change on RSI graph in pine-script

Tags: alert, pine-script

I am using the following script taken from (https://in.tradingview.com/script/fH6e5TuN-RSI-Divergence/).

```
study(title="RSI Divergence", shorttitle="RSI Divergence")

src_fast = close, len_fast = input(5, minval=1, title="Length Fast RSI")
src_slow = close, len_slow = input(14,minval=1, title="Length Slow RSI")
up_fast = rma(max(change(src_fast), 0), len_fast)
down_fast = rma(-min(change(src_fast), 0), len_fast)
rsi_fast = down_fast == 0 ? 100 : up_fast == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up_fast / down_fast))
up_slow = rma(max(change(src_slow), 0), len_slow)
down_slow = rma(-min(change(src_slow), 0), len_slow)
rsi_slow = down_slow == 0 ? 100 : up_slow == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up_slow / down_slow))
divergence = rsi_fast - rsi_slow
plotdiv = plot(divergence, color = divergence > 0 ? lime:red, linewidth = 2)
band = hline(0)

// ALERT section that I added which does not work: -------------------------------
divlong = divergence < 0 and divergence >=0
divshort = divergence > 0 and divergence <=0

alertcondition(divlong, title='Div Long', message='Div Long')
alertcondition(divshort, title='Div Short', message='Div Short')

data1 = divlong
plotshape(data1, style=shape.triangleup,location=location.bottom, color=green , title="DivUp")

data2 = divshort
plotshape(data2, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.top, color=red,title="DivDown")
```

**[Q]** Is it possible to set the alert so that it triggers when the signal line changes colors (red to green/green to red)?

---

I tried to show the points where the alerts could be triggered.

[image]

Comment: See [Alert conditions](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/annotations/Alert_conditions.html) and [How do I make an alert available from my script?](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#alerts) for how to add alerts to your script. If you need help with that, please post your entire code. This is just a snippet that doesn't compile.

Comment: Just paste it into Pine Editor section on the tradingview site and press to `Add To Chart` and also its the entire code. I added the alert approach that I tried which didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your alerts are never triggered, because the values of `divlong` and `divshort` are always false:

```
divlong = divergence < 0 and divergence >=0
divshort = divergence > 0 and divergence <=0
```

This will work:

```
study(title="RSI Divergence", shorttitle="RSI Divergence")

src_fast = close, len_fast = input(5, minval=1, title="Length Fast RSI")
src_slow = close, len_slow = input(14,minval=1, title="Length Slow RSI")
up_fast = rma(max(change(src_fast), 0), len_fast)
down_fast = rma(-min(change(src_fast), 0), len_fast)
rsi_fast = down_fast == 0 ? 100 : up_fast == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up_fast / down_fast))
up_slow = rma(max(change(src_slow), 0), len_slow)
down_slow = rma(-min(change(src_slow), 0), len_slow)
rsi_slow = down_slow == 0 ? 100 : up_slow == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up_slow / down_slow))
divergence = rsi_fast - rsi_slow
plotdiv = plot(divergence, color = divergence > 0 ? lime:red, linewidth = 2)
band = hline(0)

// ALERT section that I added which does not work: -------------------------------
// divlong = divergence < 0 and divergence >=0
// divshort = divergence > 0 and divergence <=0
divergence_past = divergence[1]
divlong = divergence >=0 and divergence_past <= 0
divshort = divergence <=0 and divergence_past >= 0


alertcondition(divlong, title='Div Long', message='Div Long')
alertcondition(divshort, title='Div Short', message='Div Short')

data1 = divlong
plotshape(data1, style=shape.triangleup,location=location.bottom, color=green , title="DivUp")

data2 = divshort
plotshape(data2, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.top, color=red,title="DivDown")
```

Comment: This works perfectly on my end. I get an alert each time the color changes. Did you set an alert? Can you post a screenshot of the settings of that alert?

Comment: I have used `divergence_past = divergence[1]
divlong = divergence >=0 and divergence_past <= 0
divshort = divergence <=0 and divergence_past >= 0` in case for the line color change